# Fermion density with Wick's theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, fermions, correlation-functions, wick-theorem

I want to calculate the expectation value
\begin{equation}
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi^\dagger_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\Psi_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle
\end{equation}
where $\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle$ is the ground state of a system of $N$ interacting fermions, and $\Psi_m(x)$ the field operator of spin $m$ and position $x$.
Using Wick's theorem I can reduce the previous expression to
\begin{equation}
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi^\dagger_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\Psi_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle
+
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi^\dagger_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle.
\end{equation}
Now, in the last term, I have calculated
\begin{equation}
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi^\dagger_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle=
\delta_{m_1m_2}\frac1{2\pi^2r^3}\bigl[\sin(k_\textrm{F}r)-k_\textrm{F}r\cos(k_\textrm{F}r)\bigr]
\end{equation}
where $r$ is $\lVert x_1-x_2\rVert$ and $k_\textrm{F}$ is the Fermi impulse of the state.

My professor told me that the other factor $\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle$ of the last term can be reduced to the one I just calculated with an appropriate change of labels and other operations such as taking the adjoint, but I'm not able to arrive at his conclusion.

So I ask you, how can I reuse the previous results in order to avoid calculating the factor $\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: note that
$$
\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\color{red}{\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)}\color{blue}{\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)}\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle=-\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\color{blue}{\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)}\color{red}{\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)}\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle+\langle\textrm{F}\rvert\{\color{red}{\Psi_{m_1}(x_1)},\color{blue}{\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)}\}\lvert\textrm{F}\rangle
$$
where
$$
\{\Psi_{m_1}(x_1),\Psi^\dagger_{m_2}(x_2)\}=\delta_{m_1m_2}\delta(x_1-x_2)
$$
denotes an anti-commutator.